# Extension of showing the open set $(0,1)$ is open in its higher dimensional counterparts.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So I understand and can show that the interval $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open. This can be done by letting $\delta =\ \frac{1}{2}min(x, 1-x)$ for instance. I'm curious as to what would be the extension for higher dimensions. For instance showing that $(0,1) \times (0,1) \times (0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R^3}$. My inclination would be to follow what was done in $\mathbb{R}$ but just include the other variables, that is let: $$\delta = \frac{1}{2} \ min(x,y,z,1-x,1-y,1-z)$$

And proceed with a line of reasoning similar to $\mathbb{R}$ but just a bit longer due to the extra variables. Would this be a good wy to go about it or what other ideas exist?

Comment: The product of open sets is an open set.

Comment: Letting $\delta =\ \frac{1}{2}min(x, 1-x)$ is not a proof, it is just crypto talk of vague value.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: It is sufficient to show that the OP is aware of the proof. That is not a vague value.

Comment: All norms are equivalent in finite dimensions, so can can use the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm in which case you can use your formula above.

Comment: @copper.hat When I was thinking of a solution I wasn't thinking in terms of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm. I was actually wondering what I could do if I were to use the Euclidean Norm..

Comment: @dc3rd: That was my point. Since $\|x\|_2 \le \sqrt{n} \|x\|_\infty$ and $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_2$ you need not worry which you use.

Comment: @Eduardo Longa  True enough, but then you need to show that the topology generated by the usual metric on $\mathbb{R^3}$ is the same as the product topology

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would indeed be a good way to go. In general, products of open sets are open in the product topology, and this makes mathematicians’ lives quite easier.

It might be a good idea that you have a look at [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) up to (including) properties for more on that.

All the best!